# Angular service worker not working with Spring Boot Server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to create a PWA with Angular/Spring Boot. When I first load the app, I can see my application files getting cached correctly.

[image]

When going offline, my application files get read from the cache, except from the js bundles that seem to give a network error...

[image]

I am using the default `ngsw.config.json` configuration generated with the `@angular/pwa` package.

```
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I run a Lighthouse report it looks like everything should be working.

The weird thing to me is that if I run the npm http-server package and proxy all my requests to my spring boot server, it works. Without the http-server proxy, the service worker keeps trying to fetch certain js bundles over the network, even they are available in the cache. This does not happen with the proxy.

Any ideas as to why I need the http-server proxy for it to work? As I would like to just use my Spring Boot server alone... Help is appreciated

Comment: That's odd. This person has the same issue as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704745/angular-service-worker-not-reading-javascript-bundles-from-cache-storage?noredirect=1#comment114425374_64704745